# DOS Batch : remove characters from string in a FOR loop

Tags: string, batch-file, for-loop, trim

I have a TXT file that contains :

```
C086002-B3116
C086014-T1234  
C086014-T1325
C086014-T1375" 
C086014-T1374"
```

These strings include both trailing whitespaces and double quotes.

I want to remove these using a FOR loop :

```
for /f %%a in (file.txt) do (
    set str=%%a
    set str=%str: =%
    set str=%str:"=%
)
```

The Shell windows is opening and closing down immediately and nothing is done on the strings... Thanks for your help on this operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to activate the delayed expansion for multiple change of a variable in a `FOR`loop

Like this :

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f  "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do (
    set str=%%a
    set str=!str: =!
    set str=!str:"=!
    echo !str!
)
```

If you need the ouput in a file :

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /f  "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do (
    set str=%%a
    set str=!str: =!
    set str=!str:"=!
    echo !str!
)) >output.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
set str=    C086014-T1374" 
echo.%str%
set str=%str:"= %
echo.%str%.
set str=%str: =%
echo.%str%.
```

This is an example what you must put in the loop body. `set str=%str:"= %` replaces `"` with  and `set str=%str: =%` removes spaces.

You can find more string manipulations [here](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)

Comment: Thanks but I still have a problem for the strings inside my file `file.txt` are not modified at all... The shell window says : `D:\file.txt><set str=C086002-B3116 set str="= set str = = >` for each value from `file.txt`.