# Batch: find files with specific content and extend existing name

Tags: batch-file, rename, findstr

I have about 100 .xml files, but its filenames are not self-explanatory. Therefore I would like to look for a specific word and extend the respecting file with this word.
Thanks to some other helpful entries, I could partially figure out how to do this, but somehow the files are not renamed.

Has anybody an idea what is wrong with my code? Thank you in advance.

```
 chcp 1252  
 SET sourcedir=P:\path  
 FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%a IN ('findstr /c:"3256" "%sourcedir%\*.xml"') DO (  
 ECHO (REN "%%a.xml" "%%a_3256.xml")  
 )  
 pause
```

Comment: Seems the `FINDSTR` command appends `:` to the results and that migth be causing problems.  I've been looking up methods to replace or remove strings from a string in DOS but thus far have not found anything helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
chcp 1252  
SET "sourcedir=P:\path"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr /m /c:"3256" "%sourcedir%\*.xml"') DO (  
    ECHO REN "%%a" "%%~na_3256%%~xa"
)  
pause
```

In your code you are using `%%a` for both arguments to `ren` command, but the second argument must only contain the name and extension, without path. You can solve it using `%%~na`, that is, the file name (without path or extension) of the file being referenced by `%%a` (`%%~xa` is the extension)

Also, *if* the string is found more than once in any file, your code will try to rename the file twice (or more). It is better to use the `/m` switch in `findstr` to only retrieve the list of files.

Rename operations are only echoed to console. If the output is right, remove the `echo` command.

Comment: I see what you mean and tried to change my code accordingly. However, I can't find the renamed file in my folder. Since it renames the file, shouldn't this be done in the same folder?

My new code looks exactly like MC ND code.

     chcp 1252
     SET sourcedir=P:\path
     FOR /f %%a IN ('findstr /m /c:"3256" "%sourcedir%\*.xml"') DO (
     ECHO %%a
     ECHO REN "%%a" "%%~na_3256%%~xa"
     )
     pause

I have to try some more this evening. Hope to find a solution/explanation soon.

Comment: @an_ja, my fault, i forget to include the last line in the answer. Now updated. Remove the `echo` command that prefixes the `ren` command.

Comment: Perfect! It's working. Thank you so much. I'm just about to start working with batch-files. It's such a nice tool.

Answer (score 0):

Dang it MC ND, right after I did some frankenstein scripting, coming up with:

After trial and error along with this great website, I managed to come up with (giving credit to [DOS Batch : remove characters from string in a FOR loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711720/dos-batch-remove-characters-from-string-in-a-for-loop) )

```
@ECHO OFF
set pathd=C:\SomePathHere
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in ('findstr /ic:SearchString %pathd%\*.xml') do (
set str=%%a
set str=!str:^:=!
echo !str!
)
```